# Git submodules not updating in Jenkins build

Tags: git, jenkins, git-submodules

I have a submodule in a project in Jenkins. I've enabled the advanced setting to recursively update submodules.

When I run the build, I see that the workspace has the files from the submodule. The problem is, it seems to be the first revision of the submodule. When I push changes (repository hosted on GitHub) Jenkins doesn't seem to update the submodule to get the right changes. Has anyone ever seen this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like I found a solution:

I added a build step to execute the following shell commands:

```
git submodule foreach git checkout master
git submodule foreach git pull
```

Comment: After you do those commands, you may need to commit in the superproject though, as the HEAD in your submodules will have been updated.

Comment: Hi Ben, could you share your solution with a bit more detail? I want to do the same thing. Also, just to confirm, your solution will git submodule update the submodules of a project into the WORKSPACE, yes?

Comment: there isn't much more detail than that.  I just added those 2 lines to my build process and it always pulls the latest version of the submodule.

Comment: As @sti says in another response here, it seems like you're trying to use Git submodules like SVN externals.  Instead of adding these commands to Jenkins, it would be better to commit the proper submodule versions to your main Git repo.  Jenkins will then always check out the same version of the submodules when building a particular version of your project.  Reproducible builds are a good thing.

Comment: @ben I came across this command that you might find more useful, esepcially if you aren't using the master branch in the submodule  `git submodule update --init --recursive`

Answer (score 109):

Note that the [Jenkins Git plugin 2.0](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+plugin+2.0+beta+testing) will have "advance submodule behaviors", which should ensure proper updates of the submodules:

[image: git 2.0]

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953299/git-submodules-not-updating-in-jenkins-build/18057696?noredirect=1#comment67088219_18057696) by [`vikramvi`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2607372/vikramvi):

> `Advanced sub-modules behavior` > "`Path of the reference repo to use during submodule update`" against this field , add submodule git url.

[image: Path]

---

[Owen B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854678/owen-b) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953299/git-submodules-not-updating-in-jenkins-build/18057696#comment89083502_18057696):

> For the authentication issue, there's now a "Use credentials from default remote of parent repository" option

Seen here in [JENKINS-20941](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20941):

[image: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/attachment/33245/Screen%20Shot%202016-07-08%20at%2010.09.17.png]

Comment: But how? Can you also provide detailed steps, which options to choose? Thanks.

Comment: @zavié I think you should choose "Advanced sub-modules behavior" and then check the checkbox "Recursively update submodules" that will appear, and click Save.

Comment: This doesn't quite work if you're using a private repository.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me with a private repo

Comment: This only works if your repo doesn't require authentication to read your git submodule. Jenkins bug.

Comment: @ErnstKuschke Is there any issue filled for that bug in the Jenkins bugtracker?

Comment: Advanced sub-modules behavior > "Path of the reference repo to use during submodule update" against this field , add submodule git url

Comment: @vikramvi Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Would be awesome, to have a screenshot, where the right option is selected (for people like me, following screenshots first, before reading anything xD)

Comment: thanks. it saved a lot of my time. easy to fix after reading your answer.

Comment: You can just check "Recursively update submodules" in Advanced sub-modules behaviours

Comment: For the authentication issue, there's now a "Use credentials from default remote of parent repository" option

Comment: @OwenB Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: how to configure branch of submodule

Comment: @vivek With `git submodule add -b aBranch...`, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309.

Comment: Seems like the first submodule gets the parent keys, but not the second one. Still buggy :(

Comment: @lunesco That would be a good opportunity for asking a separate question with details about your specific setup, so that we can try and understand what would work in your case.

Answer (score 38):

This is covered in the Git Plugin documentation on the Jenkins site under the section: [Recursive submodules](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin).

*excerpt*

> The GIT plugin supports repositories with submodules which in turn have submodules themselves. This must be turned on though: in *Job Configuration* -> Section *Source Code Management*, *Git* -> *Advanced Button* (under Branches to build) -> *Recursively update submodules*.

#### Example

From the configuration screen of your job, in the Source Code Management section, pull the *Add* button down select "Advanced sub-modules behavior".

[image: s1]

[image: s2]

Then select "Recursively update submodules":

[image: s3]

Comment: thank you but this didn't work at the time when I tried this (almost 2 years ago)

Comment: @Ben - OK, I just tried this and it worked for me. Might be related to your versions.

Comment: This only works if your repo doesn't require authentication to read your git submodule.

Comment: @ErnstKuschke - I believe Jenkins can be given an SSH key so that it too can interactive with repos that require auth.

Answer (score 32):

Are you aware that your Git repository always refers to a particular *revision* of a submodule? Jenkins is not going to automatically change the revision.

If you want to take a newer revision of the submodule into use, you have to do this in your local Git repository:

```
cd submoduledir
git pull
cd ..
git add submoduledir
git commit -m 'Updated to latest revision of submoduledir'
git push # Go and watch Jenkins build with the new revision of the submodule
```

When you do it like this, Jenkins will check out the exact same revision of the submodule during the build. Jenkins does not on its own decide which revision of the submodule to use. This is the fundamental difference between Git submodules and SVN externals.

You might want to read a good reference on submodules, e.g. http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html.

Comment: The ProGit link @sti gave is out of date. I _think_ this is the current equivalent [https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: The link is broken (HTTPS related?) - *"502 Bad Gateway"*.

Answer (score 19):

Finally stumbled on a way to do this and it's simple.

### The Issue:

The initial clone with credentials works fine but subsequent `submodule` cloning fails with incorrect credentials.

1. Automatic advanced sub-module cloning: `Source Code Management >> Additional Behaviours >>  Advanced sub-modules behaviours`: results in credential error.
2. `git submodule update --init` in the `Execute Shell` section also fails with credentials error.

### The Solution:

I'm using `jenkins-1.574`.

1. Check the `Build Environment >> SSH Agent` box.
2. Select the correct credentials (probably the same as selected in `Source Code Management` section
3. Update submodules in the `Execute Shell` section

   ```
   git submodule sync
   git submodule update --init --recursive
   ```

Here's a screen shot[image]

Comment: There's no such checkbox anymore.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Jenkins Git module, you can set it to "Wipe out workspace before build", this way it will always gets the correct sub module.

Answer (score 6):

I am using scripted pipelining with the checkout plugin. If you want the submodules to be the same as in your repository, simply switch off the trackingSubmodules option like this:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/develop']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', disableSubmodules: false, parentCredentials: true, recursiveSubmodules: false, reference: '', trackingSubmodules: false]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '[myCredentials]', url: 'https://git.myRepo.git']]])
```

Comment: This answer does not rely on a special plugin configuration.

Comment: best answer! the submodule should be configured via existing jenkins api

Answer (score 2):

On "Advanced sub-modules behaviours", check "Update tracking submodules to tip of branch"

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, works like a charm and with one simple click!

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get `scmGit` working with submodules. The build failed at native `git` call with:

> /usr/bin/git config --get submodule..url" returned status code 1:

So my ugly hack solution was initializing the submodule manually:

```
scmGit ...
sh 'git submodule add --force "<sub-path>" "<sub-name>"'
```