# Jenkins Pipeline Submodule Authentication

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a repository that contains submodules. These are developed in a publicly accessible GitHub repository. My final deployment however is in a disconnected environment with mirrored GitHub repos in GitLab, which all require authentication.

My `.gitmodules` file contains URLs for the publicly available repos. I did some `sed` replacement in the job and can update them properly, but unfortunately, I'm then not able to authenticate, since it's a separate operation from the `git url:....` step.

I can clone the project with:

```
git url: "git@my.gitlab.secure", branch: "master", credentialsId: "somecredentialid"
```

This doesn't update my submodules though unfortunately. And since I require authentication.

I also can clone using the `checkout`:

```
      checkout([                                                            
        $class: 'GitSCM',                                                   
        branches: [[name: 'master']],                               
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: true,                            
        extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption',                            
          disableSubmodules: false,                                         
          parentCredentials: true,                                          
          recursiveSubmodules: true,                                        
          reference: '', trackingSubmodules: true]],                        
          submoduleCfg: [],                                                 
          userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'somecredentialid',         
          url: 'git@my.gitlab.secure']]                                            
      ])                                                                    
    }                                                                       
  }
```

It isn't clear to me from the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) what `doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: true,` and `submoduleCfg:` are for.

I feel like the `checkout` way might be the solution, but I can't figure out how to update the `.gitmodules` to reflect the secured URLs for the submodules.

Comment: `git@my.gitlab.secure`, this is actually using `ssh://`, maybe you can change to use `https://`, what does your submodule url look like?

Comment: It can look like anything I want, right now the `.gitmodules` contains entries like this:

        url = https://github.com/someorg/somerepo.git

Regardless, those have to be changed to point to the self-hosted secure repositories.

Comment: Here is how to provide credentials to submodule checkout:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62789511/901508

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in my case which is similar to what you trying to do here; see if this helps.

```
checkout changelog: true, poll: true, scm: [
        $class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: [[name: "master"]],
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
        extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', recursiveSubmodules: true, parentCredentials: true], [$class: 'PruneStaleBranch']],
        submoduleCfg: [],
        userRemoteConfigs: [[name: 'origin', url: "Git ssh URL/${projectName}.git", credentialsId: 'Git credential']]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Having bashed my head against this a while too, here's what I found.

`doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations` is exposed as [`scm.doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/extensions/impl/SubmoduleOption.java#L167) which suggests that it invokes [`SubmoduleCombinator`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/SubmoduleCombinator.java). That doesn't look like what you want at all. The option should probably be (a) in an extension not the core plugin and (b) be called `doGenerateSubmoduleCombinationMatrix` or something.

`submoduleCfg` doesn't seem to get much obvious use in the git plugin. All I found for it was tests where it's empty.

Functionality seems to have moved into [`SubmoduleOption`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/f273d31f183105d17e37b3e6c1acf87a2782fa0c/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/extensions/impl/SubmoduleOption.java). This has method `onCheckoutCompleted(...)` that calls `git.submoduleUpdate(...)`.

So AFAICS the `extensions` entry for class `SubmoduleOption` is what you want. And the docs are a bit special.