# Jenkins multibranch - how to scan branches where jenkinsfile is placed on a submodule?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-submodules, multibranch-pipeline

I have a main repository with a submodule which contains the Jenkinsfile . With this I want create a multibranch pipeline job for that main repository. 
But it's not working. It works when the Jenkinsfile is not in the submodule but it doesn't detect the branches when Jenkinsfile its on the submodule.

How can I get the branches be detected when the Jenkinsfile is placed on a submodule?

Comment: You can check existing threads here, how can setup submodule behavior for classic style jobs and pipelines https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953299/git-submodules-not-updating-in-jenkins-build and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290133/jenkins-pipeline-git-command-submodule-update/42293620

Comment: Thanks! I tested the second solution but it didn't worked. The first does not apply to my use case cause this is produced by the jenkins multibranch plugin where i can not add that commands.