# Multibranch jenkins - jenkinsfile is on submodule

Tags: jenkins

I have the same problem as in:
[Jenkins multibranch - how to scan branches where jenkinsfile is placed on a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674552/jenkins-multibranch-how-to-scan-branches-where-jenkinsfile-is-placed-on-a-subm?newreg=edd2422fdac94f2ba29985732a888054)

Note that both repositories are placed on a private gitlab server and they are set as private. However i've no problem in checkout both interdependently on Jenkins.

I have my jenkinsfile for a branch placed on a submodule like so:

```
main/
   ...
   submodule/ -> submodule
      jenkinsfile
```

But i'm unable to run a Multibranch pipeline. The scan cannot detect the jenkinfile:

```
Checking branches...
  Checking branch main
      ‘submodule/jenkinsfile’ not found
    Does not meet criteria
Processed 1 branches
```

I've tried all the options on the following thread: [Git submodules not updating in Jenkins build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953299/git-submodules-not-updating-in-jenkins-build)

But none work.

Versions:

- jenkins version: Jenkins 2.332.3
- Git plugin Version 4.11.5  GitHub
- Branch Source Plugin Version 1677.v731f745ea_0cf

As anyone figure out the solution to this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to resolve my issues based on this thread: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/9243/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-jenkinsfile-from-a-git-submodule-in-a-multibranch-pipeli

i've installed this plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/remote-file/ and it solved my issues.