# jenkins build and push docker image jenkins

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline to build and push docker image to Nexus
the maven project is composed of 3 submodules like this:

```
+pom.xml
+api folder
  ----->  Dockerfile
+core folder
    -----> Dockerfile
+test
    -----> pom.xml

docker.withRegistry("https://" + dockerRegistry, jenkinsCredential) {
 dockerImage = docker.build tagImage
 //  dockerImage.push()
  }
```

the problem is that the Dockerfile does not exist in the main project that's why I have this error: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat  no such file or directory
is there any solution please?

Comment: Then also pull the submodules -> does this answer your question? [Git submodules not updating in Jenkins build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953299/git-submodules-not-updating-in-jenkins-build)

Comment: Which `Dockerfile` do you want to build?

Comment: I want to build every Dockerfile