# Checkout specific directory with GIT using SourceTree

Tags: bitbucket, git-checkout, atlassian-sourcetree

My iPhone app is currently hosted on a BitBucket repository. I would like the graphic designer in my team to be able to view and checkout the graphic assets directory and to perform commits on it without giving visibility to the whole source code. How is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> graphic assets directory

If that directory is referenced in your iPhone app as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, meaning as an independent repo, you can then add your graphic designer as a collaborator on that repo alone.

He/she can commit on that repo, and you can configure your submodule to [follow the latest of those commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309) in your submodule within your main ("parent") repo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if this can be easily achievable with SourceTree?

Comment: Also,do you think it's possible to give an user the permission to checkout/commit on a specific folder?

Comment: @Claus with submodule, you don't need to give permission to checkout/commit a specific folder: the all "graphic assets directory" is a repo for which the designer has full access. He/she doesn't have to even know about the "parent" repo which will use that "graphic assets directory". So it is possible with BitBucket, through permissions: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Repository+privacy%2C+permissions%2C+and+more: but that is for a full repo, not a directory.