# How to share files/folders across git repo?

Tags: git, symlink, git-submodules, subtree

I have a git repository, inside there are files/folders, that I want to share across repo.

```
repo/
     .git/
     html-coding
          css-shared
     js-app
          css-shared
          ttf-shared
     font-files
          ttf-shared
```

Using Submodules for this task looks like overkill. At times of SVN I've used snv:externals flag, which worked just fine for my purposes.

Subtree is again referencing to external repos, which I don't need at all. Something simple like symbolic links would be acceptable. But I need it cross-platform, since my devs are on Mac, Win and Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using Submodules for this task looks like overkill

Using [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) is the right solution, especially since they now can follow the latest commit of a branch (since [git1.8.2, March 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309)).
In that aspect, they act as svn:external.

Comment: Note to self: not related but still interesting: http://www.mail-archive.com/git-users@googlegroups.com/msg02382.html