# How do I force git to always use the master branch?

Tags: git, branch, clone

I have some Xcode project I'm trying to clone from GitHub using git, and it has external submodules as well. Whenever I try to clone, it keeps putting these external submodules as well as every folder in the project on "(no branch)" instead of master. This is what I'm doing in Terminal:

```
git clone git@github.com:******.git
cd ******
git submodule update --init
cd External/******
git submodule update --init
cd External/******
git submodule update --init
```

If I cd into any folder and do git branch, I get this:

```
git branch
* (no branch)
master
```

Is there a way I can force git clone to use the master branch everywhere?

Comment: `git submodule update --init --recursive` should be enough

Comment: Do the submodules have different `master` branches than the parent repo? If you switch them to `master`, will the submodules still work with the parent repository, or will their code be incompatible?

Comment: If I switch them to master, it works, but I have to go through and manually do it to each folder, which is annoying. In fact, if I don't switch them to master, I get compile errors where it can't find files that exist.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This requires **git 1.8.2** or later (March 2013)

It depends on how those submodules are declared in the `.gitmodules`:

See "[git submodule tracking latest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309)"

That would allow you to follow the master branch.
Update your current `.gitmodules` with a:

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch master
git submodule update --remote --recursive
```

Note that the submodule *still* won't be on any branch. Simply their SHA1 would be the one of `origin/master`.
You would still need to `checkout master` for each of them.

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git checkout master
```