# Github and Git two repos in one project

Tags: git, github

So I want to have a project set up like this:

```
-- Project
   -- .git
   -- SubProject (Used by project)
      -- .git
```

The idea is that on github `Project` is a repo and `SubProject` is another repo. if I set up a project like this, does this mean that `Project` - on github - will show a "refrence" symbol to `SubProject` repo?

Also - if this is the case, when Person B pulls `Project` down to work on it will it also pull the reference project inside - `SubProject` ?? Or will they have to then pull that project?

right now I have the projects separate on git hub - which is how I want them, they are two projects - how ever `Project` uses `SubProject` and I feel that when I develop `SubProject` I am always developing it inside of `Project` then copying over to `SubProject` and committing - theirs no history their. I want to develop `SubProject` inside of project so that `subproject` gets some history.

**How will this work for pushing, pulling, merging, branching and at the end of the day tagging and zipping up to then distribute?** - Project would be the one tagged and distributed -

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: care toy give more input?

Comment: Submodules is exactly what you want. Read Iarsmans' link

Answer (score 0):

You can use, as mentioned, submodules.

As I explain in "[True nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1979194/6309)", it is a good way to keep a fix reference to another repo (SubProject) from a "parent repo" (Project).

Both repo have their history independent and separate:

- making a branch in one won't make a branch in the other.
- make a tag in the parent repo won't tag the submodule repo (but it will include the SHA1 of that submodule at the time of the tag, guaranteeing that pulling the parent repo from that tag will restore the right version of the submodule).

Note that, from git 1.8.2+, you can [configure your submodule to track a branch of its own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309).
Or you can [convert an existing submodule to track a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309).
And you can [remove a submodule at any time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309).