# Remote Git Repository Infrastructure suggestion? (Blue Maps)

Tags: git, github, infrastructure

I have been thinking awhile how to achieve the below goals for quite awhile. Think I'm not expert in Git to have enough knowledge to craft a good infrastructure. Anyone of you can give me the suggestions?

## Scenario:

**Product** A, B, C
**Client** X, Y, Z

```
Client X has Product A only.
Client Y has Product A and B.
Client Z has Product B and C.
```

Initially I was thinking the base should be Repo A, B and C separately and each of them will have separate module in different folder in case Client has specific request on the product. But later something comes into my mind, what if I fetch and pull from Repo A? Will the separate module being pulled together at once? How should I do it or any other better infrastructure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what if I fetch and pull from `Repo A`? Will the separate module being pulled together at once?

No: each repo is independent.

I would recommend three additional repos, for referencing the right [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

- `RepoX` for `Client X`: references one submodule `A`
- `RepoY` for `Client Y`: references two submodules `A` and `B`
- `RepoX` for `Client Z`: references two submodules `B` and `C`

The idea (with submodules) to record the exact SHA1 of each product you need for a given client.
that way, if you pull one `Product` repo:

- it doesn't have any influence on the other `Product` repos
- you go back one level up in the parent repo (a `Client` repo), add and commit the new state of your submodule, recording the change you made in said submodule.

Comment: Hi I roughly got the idea which said to have extra repo to deploy submodules. But by referring to this site http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules My eyes started to get dizzy.. Is this the only option?

Comment: @EricT yes, but submodules are really trivial: `git submodule add /url/to/RepoA repoA`. `git submodule update --init`. Done. I documented more on submodules at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1979194/6309

Comment: 1 more question, as I read submodules is created in a subdirectory. If the project is in framework style wouldn't this be an issue like you need a folder in controller, another in view and one more in model? How to overcome this situation?

Comment: @EricT if one assumes one parent repo including the controller, view and model, it would also include a folder for the submodule, and then you can symlink said folder in each controller, view and model directories.

Comment: ohh after proof of concept, I manage to gone through the tutorial but not confidence against the symlink as in http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules says "This is an important point with submodules: you record them as the exact commit they’re at. You can’t record a submodule at master or some other symbolic reference.". Not sure if I mistakenly understand that phrase :/

Comment: @EricT yes, but that tutorial is old: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309: you can make a submodule *follow* a branch.

Comment: Hi @VonC, is it possible to get your messenger to discuss further about the concept? Don't know if it is right to ask for personal details this way.

Comment: @EricT sure: vonc at laposte dot net

Comment: Hi @VonC, sadly to tell that I couldn't read french. Not sure if you have the common one like fb, win live msnger, or some others?

Comment: @EricT it is an email address, but know that any generic question about Git will be bumped back to Stack Overflow (where I and other will answer them).