# GIT: add only some files from remote repository as submodule

Tags: git

I need to add some JS library to my project and I also want to have ability to update that library from it's repo (that's why I'm adding it as submodule). But I need only on 1 file from that repo to be placed withing my JS directory, whereas library repository contain tests, coffeescript sources and so on, which I do not need in my repository. So the question is - how to add not whole repo as submodule, but single file/directory from it?

I suppose this is somehow possible with help of [Git Sparse checkouts](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout) but not sure if I'm on the right way with this...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible and I've done it many times.

All you need to do is to create a branch of the repository that you are adding as a submodule and strip out all the code that you don't want and add the submodule with that branch.

As an example, look at this [repository](https://github.com/Abizern/KVOWithBlocks)

Comment: Thank you, Abizem, this looks like a good solution, But since I'm very weak in git I can't image how I can set up auto update from dev to master branch. Without auto update, if I have to do it manually it would be almost the same as if I would replace that file without even using submodules.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "from dev to master" and "autoupdate".

Comment: `master` branch now contain only one final compiled file in the root of repo, `development` contain everything needed for development and this same file somewhere in subdirectory. Now if something would be pushed in `development` branch - file in `master` also should be updated - this is what I mean autoupdate. Are there any way to do this?

Comment: Just do a merge.  If you removed the files correctly from master, then you'll hardly have to clean anything up.

Comment: it was not obvious for that file in /foo/bar/blah.js from one branch will be merged with blah.js of another branch. Still can't explain how but this work )

Comment: This isn't a good answer. You'll still need to manually update the _submodule branch_ with `master` . Defeats the purpose of submodule then

Answer (score 6):

To add to [Abizern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41116/abizern)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20986570/6309) (upvoted), you can declare your submodule (set to the branch which contains the files you want) to **[follow that branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309)** ([`git submodule` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)):

```
git submodule add -b yourSubmoduleBranch /url/to/your/submodule/repo
```

If you have already added your submodule, without the `-b`, you can add that option easily enough: see "[Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)".

```
# Make sure your submodule is actually at the latest of that branch:
cd path/to/your/submodule
git checkout -b branch --track origin/branch
# record that on the parent repo
cd /path/to/your/parent/repo
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch <branch>
git add yourSubmodule
git commit -m "Submodule now follows branch"
```

All you need to do for your submodule to reflect your latest modifications is now, on the parent repo level:

```
git submodule update --init --remote --recursive
```

---

As noted by [frmbelz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1496974/frmbelz) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985983/git-add-only-some-files-from-remote-repository-as-submodule/20988949#comment133166025_20988949), my [2018 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53233492/6309) using `info/sparse-checkout` or [`git clone --filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---filterltfilter-specgt) does allow to pull just a couple of files into submodule.

Comment: VonC, looks your later [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53233492/1496974) does this. Using that answer I could pull just a couple of files into submodule.

Comment: @frmbelz Thank you for your feedback, good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.