# Git submodule prepare for sparse checkout

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule to be used with sparse checkout. Without sparse checkout I'd do

```
git submodule update --init <path/to/submodule>
```

but how to initialize the submodule repository empty without fetching it (or fetching it, but not checking it out) yet, so I can invoke

```
cd <path/to/submodule>
git config core.sparseCheckout true
cd <../../..>
echo <subdir-to-get> .git/modules/<path/to/submodule>/info/sparse-checkout
```

Unfortunately

```
git submodule init <path/to/submodule>
```

does not create the repository in `.git/modules/<path/to/submodule>` and the file `<path/to/submodule>/.git`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45689692/6309), to clone the submodule as normal repository first, and then use [`git submodule absorbgitdirs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-absorbgitdirs).

By cloning first with a depth of 1, you don't get too many data:

```
git clone --depth=1 --no-checkout an/Url <path/to/submodule>
git submodule add an/Url <path/to/submodule>
git submodule absorbgitdirs
```

Then, you can modify the `.git/modules/<path/to/submodule>/info/sparse-checkout`

```
git -C <path/to/submodule> config core.sparseCheckout true
echo 'foo/*' >>.git/modules/<path/to/submodule>/info/sparse-checkout
```

Finally, get only the files you want:

```
git submodule update --force --checkout <path/to/submodule>
```

---

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52780680/git-submodule-prepare-for-sparse-checkout/53233492?noredirect=1#comment124380360_53233492) by [Janus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212538/janus), one can do even better (fewer data) with a [`git clone --filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---filterltfilter-specgt), which I illustrated in 2019 with "[What is the `git clone --filter` option's syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52916879/6309)":

```sh
#fastest clone possible:
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout https://github.com/git/git
cd git
suburl=$(git config -f .gitmodules --get submodule.<sub>.url)
git submodule update --init --force --checkout <sub>
```

(Replace `<sub>` by the submodule name entry from your `.gitmodules`)

Comment: what is `git -C` I don't even see that documented.

Comment: @EvanCarroll But it is documented: https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--Cltpathgt. Since 2013: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20115526/6309

Comment: This is the most concise working answer for this problem I have found.
A few extra pointers: If `depth=1` is still too much data, you can check out a tag at the initial commit with `git clone --branch initial ...`, alternatively you can use `--filter=blob:none`.
Also, to get the URL of the repo, you can use `git config -f .\.gitmodules --get submodule.<sub>.url`
Finally, you can skip the `git submodule add` and instead use `git submodule update ---init --force --checkout sub` as the final step.

Comment: @Janus Thank you for this feedback. Could you review my last edit to this answer and correct it, if I have misunderstood your proposed sequence of commands?

Comment: Thanks for updating @VonC! Two small things: if you include the `--init` in the final `submodule update` (as you do now), it is ok to drop the `git submodule add` in the first code block. Also, the `.\.gitmodules` is windows gunk from me -- probably `.gitmodules` is more portable.

Comment: @Janus But for the `update --init` to works, it needs to find the URL in the `.gitmodules` file.  Hence the `git submodule add`, no?

Comment: Ah, maybe we are looking at two different scenarios: I am trying to check out for a repo where .gitmodules is already populated

Comment: @Janus OK, makes sense. My answer might not apply to that scenario, I presume...

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying using the below approaches, simplified from the other answer by VonC and community.

To init existing submodule using a filter:

```
git submodule update --init --filter=blob:none
```

To add submodule using a filter:

```
git clone --filter=blob:none sub/mod/url [submodpath]
git submodule add sub/mod/url [submodpath] # doesn't download
git submodule absorbgitdirs
```

Comment: Nice summary. Upvoted.

Comment: Which git version started supporting --filter for "git submodule update"? Git 2.34.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't have it yet.