# git sparse-checkout of a submodule from a root repo

Tags: git, git-submodules, sparse-checkout

I have a [main repo](https://github.com/KVM-VMI/kvm-vmi/) with 4 submodules:

- kvm
- libvmi
- qemu
- nitro

and I would like to `sparse-checkout` `kvm`, to filter out a few annoying files that are not comptabile with filesystem limitations on Windows 
(`AUX` is a reserved filename, and kvm tree contains `aux.{h|c}`)

I understand how to do a `sparse-checkout` on a normal repository, but when I do the same on a submodule, it doesn't work, the `.git/modules` directory is missing:

```
git clone https://github.com/KVM-VMI/kvm-vmi/
git -C kvm config core.sparseCheckout true
echo "!drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/i2c/aux.*" >> .git/modules/kvm/info/sparse-checkout # ignore aux.*
echo "/*" >> .git/modules/kvm/info/sparse-checkout # checkout everything else
git submodule update --init
```

The first `echo` command will fail because the `.git/modules` hasn't been created.

I don't know who is responsible for creating this directory.

Am I missing an "`init`" command somewhere ?

Note:

I have been looking for solutions on Stackoverflow, or from blog posts:

- [Git submodule prepare for sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52780680/git-submodule-prepare-for-sparse-checkout)
- [How to do submodule sparse-checkout with Git?](https://issue.life/questions/45688121)

but they don't work for me because I don't want to clone a separate `kvm` repo and later on add it to my main repo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone the kvm repo yourself, with `--no-checkout` aka `-n`, to the `kvm` directory.  Set it up as you like, `git submodule absorbgitdirs kvm` from the superproject to move the repo and set its `core.worktree` and leave the `.git` breadcrumb file in that `kvm`  work tree, and `git -C kvm reset --hard` to finish the checkout.

```
git clone https://github.com/KVM-VMI/kvm-vmi
cd kvm-vmi
git submodule init
git clone -n `git config submodule.kvm.url` kvm
mkdir kvm/.git/info
```

and you're ready for

```
mkdir kvm/.git/info
git -C kvm config core.sparsecheckout true
printf %s\\n '/*' '!aux.*' >kvm/.git/info/sparse-checkout
git submodule absorbgitdirs kvm
git -C kvm reset --hard
```