# is it possible not to have extra subdirectory when using Git - submodule - sparse-checkout?

Tags: git, svn, git-submodules, svn-externals, sparse-checkout

I want to mimic behavior like svn:externals: I have a master project and I have some "common" code in another repository. With SVN I would do:

```
svn co <url>/src common
```

and my folder structure would be:

```
repo/common/*.cpp
```

Now with git + submodule + sparse checkout this is a lot more complicated and I have an extra subdirectory layer when I add the submodule;

```
git submodule add <url> common
```

now my folder structure is:

```
repo/common/src/*.cpp
repo/common/lib/...
```

with sparse checkout I can make sure only to checkout the src folder, but than I still have one more layer (src) compared to the svn:externals solution:

```
repo/common/src/*.cpp
```

is there a better solution for common code? Or a way to clean this up? I know that everything will be working; it's just not so clean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot avoid the extra folder from the submodule, but you can add a symbolic link (even on Windows) in order to find the content you want.

Add your submodule with its repo name:

```
git submodule add -b master /url/of/repo
```

Add a symlink:

```
ln -s repo/src common
```

Don't forget to add the '`-b master`' if you want your repo to follow its `master` branch.
This is possible since git 1.8.2: see "[`git submodule` tracking latest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309)".

---

Even the [Git 2.25 and its `git sparse-checkout` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62617098/6309) would not avoid the extra folder level "`common`".

Comment: Wow thanks for the hint on the '-b master' option! I'll check that out further...

Comment: @ChrisMaes yes, it is a *local* config you associate with your submodule. Any `git submodule update --remote` would then update the content of the submodule *after* fetching the submodule upstream branch.

Comment: Is this answer still correct, given recent changes to both submodules and sparse-checkout?

Comment: @eggyal Yes it is. I have presented the Git 2.25 `git sparse-checkout` new command in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62617098/6309. But in the OP's context, you would still have an intermediate folder level for any submodule you would be using.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  In my case I have a submodule that's concerned with only a tiny fraction of the whole repo, rather than just wanting to avoid an intermediate folder, but I guess the working set will have to include the full submodule for now.

Comment: @eggyal you can still include only a subset of the submodule, but still at the cost of an extra folder, hence the symlink suggestion of this 2014 answer.

Comment: Ah, I'd misunderstood.  Should first have read the answer to which you linked in your previous comment.  Many thanks.