# How to do submodule sparse-checkout with Git?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-sparse-checkout

There are a lot of articles and SO questions about sparse-checkout. Unfortunately I did not find concrete examples. I would like to get this following example work:

#### Create a submodule

```
cd ~
mkdir sub && cd $_
git init 
mkdir foo && touch $_/foo
mkdir bar && touch $_/bar
git add .
git commit -am "Initial commit"
```

#### Create a project

```
cd ~
mkdir project && cd $_
git init
git submodule add ../sub sub
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.sub.shallow true
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.sub.sparsecheckout true
echo foo/* > .git/modules/sub/info/sparse-checkout
git commit -am "Initial commit"
git submodule update
cd sub
git checkout .
```

A this point I am expecting `sub` folder to only contain `foo/foo` not `bar`. Unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
$ ls
bar/ foo/
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`git submodule add` itself checks out the submodule.

What succeeded for me was:

```sh
git init
# I did not find a way to add submodule in 1 step without checking out
git clone --depth=1 --no-checkout ../sub sub
git submodule add ../sub sub
git submodule absorbgitdirs
# note there is no "submodule.sub.sparsecheckout" key
git -C sub config core.sparseCheckout true
# note quoted wildcards to avoid their expansion by shell
echo 'foo/*' >>.git/modules/sub/info/sparse-checkout
git submodule update --force --checkout sub
```

Or from a git URL:

```bash
# Initialize main repo (if needed)
git init

# Checkout the to-be submodule
# I did not find a way to add submodule in 1 step without checking out
git clone --depth=1 --no-checkout git@example.com:username/some-repo.git path/some-repo

# Add as a submodule
git submodule add git@example.com:username/some-repo.git path/some-repo

# Move the .git dir from path/some-repo/.git into parent repo's .git 
git submodule absorbgitdirs

# Note there is no "submodule.sub.sparsecheckout" key
git -C sub config core.sparseCheckout true

# This pattern determines which files within some-repo.git get checked out. 
# Note quoted wildcards to avoid their expansion by shell
echo 'foo/*'  >> .git/modules/path/some-repo/info/sparse-checkout

# Actually do the checkout
git submodule update --force --checkout sub
```

Comment: Have you updated `echo bar >>.git/modules/sub/info/sparse-checkout` with your pattern?

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! Even though I think in this case `absorbgitdirs` does nothing because `submodule add` already puts the submodules git directory inside to root `.git`. Calling it doesn't hurt though

Comment: in the second example (with URL) there are inconsistencies between `path/some-repo` and `sub`, it should obviously be the same thing

Comment: Is there a way to save this configuration so these commands don't have to be ran every time the parent repository is checked out?

Comment: What is the git submodule absorbgitdirs line about? Can a real example be given?

Answer (score 8):

To add to [max630](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303202/max630)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45689692/6309):

- [since Git 2.25](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515426/6309) (Q1 2020), you would use the new command [`git sparse-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout)
- And with Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), The effect of `sparse checkout` settings on submodules is documented.

Meaning if you make the main repository itself sparsely checked out, in addition of the submodule (already sparse, as in max630's answer),  using `git sparse-checkout` on the main repository will not affect the submodule negatively (ie. removing it by mistake while there is work in progress in it).

See [commit e7d7c73](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e7d7c73249bf68be1fd912db045dcb4b6a0b6570) (10 Jun 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 81be89e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81be89e0bee5bebc478a19b317d8ef4d5f6704a9), 22 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git-sparse-checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e7d7c73249bf68be1fd912db045dcb4b6a0b6570): clarify interactions with submodules
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Ignoring the sparse-checkout feature momentarily, if one has a submodule and creates local branches within it with unpushed changes and maybe adds some untracked files to it, then we would want to avoid accidentally removing such a submodule.
>
> So, for example with [git.git](https://github.com/git/git), if you run
>
> ```
> git checkout v2.13.0
> ```
>
> then the sha1collisiondetection/ submodule is NOT removed even though it did not exist as a submodule until v2.14.0.
>
> Similarly, if you only had v2.13.0 checked out previously and ran
>
> ```
> git checkout v2.14.0
> ```
>
> the sha1collisiondetection/ submodule would NOT be automatically initialized despite being part of v2.14.0.
>
> In both cases, git requires submodules to be initialized or deinitialized separately.
>
> Further, we also have special handling for submodules in other commands such as clean, which requires two `--force` flags to delete untracked submodules, and some commands have a `--recurse-submodules` flag.
>
> sparse-checkout is very similar to checkout, as evidenced by the similar name -- it adds and removes files from the working copy.
>
> However, for the same avoid-data-loss reasons we do not want to remove a submodule from the working copy with checkout, we do not want to do it with sparse-checkout either.
>
> So submodules need to be separately initialized or deinitialized; changing sparse-checkout rules should not automatically trigger the removal or vivification of submodules.
>
> I believe the previous wording in [`git sparse-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout) about submodules was only about this particular issue.
>
> Unfortunately, the previous wording could be interpreted to imply that submodules should be considered active regardless of sparsity patterns.
>
> Update the wording to avoid making such an implication.
>
> It may be helpful to consider two example situations where the differences in wording become important:
>
> In the future, we want users to be able to run commands like
>
> ```
> git clone --sparse=moduleA --recurse-submodules $REPO_URL
> ```
>
> and have sparsity paths automatically set up and have submodules *within the sparsity paths* be automatically initialized.
>
> We do not want all submodules in any path to be automatically initialized with that command.
>
> Similarly, we want to be able to do things like
>
> ```
> git -c sparse.restrictCmds grep --recurse-submodules $REV $PATTERN
> ```
>
> and search through `$REV` for `$PATTERN` within the recorded sparsity patterns.
>
> We want it to recurse into submodules within those sparsity patterns, but do not want to recurse into directories that do not match the sparsity patterns in search of a possible submodule.

So [the documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e7d7c73249bf68be1fd912db045dcb4b6a0b6570/Documentation/git-sparse-checkout.txt#L190-L218) now includes:

> If your repository contains one or more submodules, then submodules are populated based on interactions with the `git submodule` command.
> Specifically, `git submodule init -- <path>` will ensure the submodule at `<path>` is present, while `git submodule deinit [-f] -- <path>` will remove the files for the submodule at `<path>` (including any untracked files, uncommitted changes, and unpushed history).
> Similar to how sparse-checkout removes files from the working tree but still leaves entries in the index, deinitialized submodules are removed from the working directory but still have an entry in the index.
>
> Since submodules may have unpushed changes or untracked files, removing them could result in data loss.
> Thus, changing sparse inclusion/exclusion rules will not cause an already checked out
> submodule to be removed from the working copy.
> Said another way, just as `checkout` will not cause submodules to be automatically removed or initialized even when switching between branches that remove or add
> submodules, using `sparse-checkout` to reduce or expand the scope of "interesting" files will not cause submodules to be automatically deinitialized or initialized either.
>
> Further, the above facts mean that there are multiple reasons that "tracked" files might not be present in the working copy: sparsity pattern application from sparse-checkout, and submodule initialization state.
> Thus, commands like `git grep` that work on tracked files in the working copy may return results that are limited by either or both of these restrictions.

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), "[`git grep`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/628c13cceed408526df39dbbd4a0d00bc4f34803/Documentation/git-grep.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep))</sup> has been tweaked to be limited to the sparse checkout paths.

Since you might need `git grep` in sparse-checkedout submodules, this is important.

See [commit 42d906b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42d906bec48c95d66cb669ee41ce04330f74a98b) (09 Feb 2021) by [Matheus Tavares (`matheustavares`)](https://github.com/matheustavares).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 628c13c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/628c13cceed408526df39dbbd4a0d00bc4f34803), 25 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`grep`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42d906bec48c95d66cb669ee41ce04330f74a98b): honor sparse-checkout on working tree searches
>
> <sup>Suggested-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matheus Tavares</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> On a sparse checked out repository, [`git grep`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/42d906bec48c95d66cb669ee41ce04330f74a98b/Documentation/git-grep.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep))</sup> (without `--cached`) ends up searching the cache when an entry matches the search pathspec and has the `SKIP_WORKTREE` bit set.
>
> This is confusing both because the sparse paths are not expected to be in a working tree search (as they are not checked out), and because the output mixes working tree and cache results without distinguishing them.
> (Note that `grep` also resorts to the cache on working tree searches that include `--assume-unchanged` paths.
> But the whole point in that case is to assume that the contents of the index entry and the file are the same.
> This does not apply to the case of sparse paths, where the file isn't even expected to be present.)
>
> Fix that by teaching grep to honor the sparse-checkout rules for working tree searches.
> If the user wants to grep paths outside the current sparse-checkout definition, they may either update the sparsity rules to materialize the files, or use `--cached` to search all blobs registered in the index.

And, still for sparsed-checked out submodules:

With Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), "[`git grep`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/67bf4a83e9fcd18a2135215d4fd18e84f742d09b/Documentation/git-grep.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep))</sup> learned to expand the sparse-index more lazily and on demand in a sparse checkout.

See [commit 7cae762](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cae7627c459ae5d0cd8f4c1ff76601e6c952bf3) (22 Sep 2022) by [Shaoxuan Yuan (`ffyuanda`)](https://github.com/ffyuanda).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 67bf4a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67bf4a83e9fcd18a2135215d4fd18e84f742d09b), 10 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/grep.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cae7627c459ae5d0cd8f4c1ff76601e6c952bf3): integrate with sparse index
>
> <sup>Suggested-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Victoria Dye</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Shaoxuan Yuan</sup>

> Turn on sparse index and remove `ensure_full_index()`.
>
> Before this patch, `git-grep` utilizes the `ensure_full_index()` method to expand the index and search all the entries.
> Because this method requires walking all the trees and constructing the index, it is the slow part within the whole command.
>
> To achieve better performance, this patch uses `grep_tree()` to search the sparse directory entries and get rid of the `ensure_full_index()` method.
>
> Why `grep_tree()` is a better choice over `ensure_full_index()`?
>
> 1. `grep_tree()` is as correct as `ensure_full_index()`.
>    `grep_tree()` looks into every sparse-directory entry (represented by a tree) recursively when looping over the index, and the result of doing so matches the result of expanding the index.
> 2. `grep_tree()` utilizes pathspecs to limit the scope of searching.
>    `ensure_full_index()` always expands the index, which means it will always walk all the trees and blobs in the repo without caring if the user only wants a subset of the content, i.e. using a pathspec.
>    On the other hand, `grep_tree()` will only search the contents that match the pathspec, and thus possibly walking fewer trees.
> 3. `grep_tree()` does not construct and copy back a new index, while `ensure_full_index()` does. This also saves some time.

Comment: Hi there! I didn't get how Git 2.28 would simplify/improve @max630 answer. Would you mind post/describe the equivalent commands to achieve something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45689692/6108874 ? Thx!

Comment: @GerardBosch This is only to complement max630's answer by describe how the new `git sparse-checkout` command interact with submodules.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was a full answer! Maybe you can update it just to state what you said in this comment :) Thanks anyway!!

Comment: @GerardBosch Sure thing. I have edited the introduction of this answer, to make its purpose clearer.