# Git External Resource into Dev Branch Automatically

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Here is the scenario...
I have a repo that is a basic setup for any sites I may work out. It uses some external resources such as the Foundation Grid and Cycle2. Is it possible within my dev branch to retrieve files from these resources Git repos and pull them into specific folders as if they are part of my repo, automatically?

So, lets say on my desktop I do a get latest, can my repo also get the latest files from the Foundation repo (only files I specify or only those I do not ignore) and pull them into specific folders in my dev repo? Is this possible? If not, what would be the best way to do something like this, to ensure that I always have the latest versions of external resources?

Answer (score 1):

> pull them into specific folders

Not exactly: you can declare your Foundation repo as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** of your desktop project repo, and get those files within one specific folder.
You could then have a post-check hook in that submodule in order to copy those files elsewhere in your parent repo (where there would be ignored by a `.gitignore` in that parent repo)

A submodule can be updated in a way it follows the latest commits of a given upstream branch.
See "[git submodule tracking latest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309)".

Comment: IS there good examples of a post-check hook used in this scenario you can point me toward?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) to have another indipended repo inside your main `git repo`. By using [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) you can have your submodules updated.