# How do you develop along with a git submodule?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-flow

Here is my project structure

```
MainProject
|  README.md
|  src/
|  lib/      # this is a submodule
```

When I develop `MainProject`, I will also develop `lib/`, I mean `MainProject/lib/`.

When I do push, I will copy all changes in `MainProject/lib/*` into `MainProject/../lib/`, which is a separate  git directory, then push.

After that I will do a submodule update in `MainProject/lib/` to latest from remote.

Then I will commit and push changes in `MainProject`.

It suffers. How do you develop along with a git submodule?

**ADD**

I want all changes in `lib/` pushed to remote `lib` repository.
And all changes beside `lib/` in `MainProject` pushed to remote `MainProject`.

So if I directly put to remote `lib` repository inside `MainProject/lib`
And then add and commit and push changes beside `lib/` in  `MainProject` to remote.

If someone else clone `MainProject` and do `submodule update`, will he get the latest sources?

My `.gitmodules`:

```
 [submodule "lib"]
    path = lib
    url = git@github.com:XXX/YYY.git
    branch = master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to copy your changes: you can push directly from `MainProject/lib` to the same upstream repo (the one in `git remote origin`) than the upstream repo (`git remote origin`) found in `MainProject/../lib`.

`MainProject/lib` is a nested repo in its own right: you can add commit and push them directly from it.

But then, you have to go back to `MainProject/`, add, commit and push in order to record the new gitlink ([the special entry in the index of the parent repo which records the SHA1 of the submodule lib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309))

---

> add and commit and push changes beside `lib/` in `MainProject` to remote

No: when you commit anyhting in lib, that will change the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (the 'lib' entry in `MainProject` index)

By "going back to `MainProject`" (meaning, you were in `MainProject/lib` and you do `cd ..`), you can do a git add ., which will:

- add all your changes beside lib/
- record the new SHA1 associated with `lib/` submodule (the '`lib`' gitlink entry)

But pushing the `MainProject`, complete with the updated gitlink 'lib' entry, you are making sure that anyone cloning your `MainProject` will get back `lib` at that exact updated SHA1.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean "back to MainProject/, add, commit and push..."? I have added something to my post. Please read and help. Thanks.

Comment: @Sato I have edited my answer. It is important to realize how 'lib' is viewed from the perspective of its parent repo `MainProject`: as a gitlink entry in the index, in order to record the exact SHA1 at which the submodule is checked out. If you create a new commit in the submodule, you need to push it, but also go back to the main project and add/commit that gitlink entry.

Comment: So when others clone `MyProject` and do a `submodule update`, it will get the exact SHA1(gitlink entry recorded in `MainProject`) not just HEAD?

Comment: @Sato yes, a submodule *always* checks out at a fixed SHA1. Then, you can configure a submodule to update itself the HEAD of a specific branch. See my answers at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309