# How to turn on git auto-fetch?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have several git projects which I want to fetch everyday (in the morning for example) and checkout to the last commit (if there are no local changes of course) to the branch "origin/dev" (e.g. it may not be a master branch). So how to do this for all projects in the directory?

Comment: There is no such thing as autofetch. You might consider writing a cron job though

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a *nix/mac you could use the following bash script and create a cron job/launchdaemon task:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ls -d */ | while read folder; do
    if [ -d "$folder/.git" ]; then
        cd "$folder"
        git pull # CHANGE THIS TO YOUR NEEDS
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

> How to do this for all projects in the directory?

One way would be to (experiment in a separate local directory):

- create a local repo in that directory
- add all those Git repos projects as submodules (git add submodule -b dev url/git/repo/for/a/project): they will be set to track the dev branch
- every day (with a cron job for instance), do a `git submodule update --recursive --remote`: that will fetch and checkout the latest from origin/dev for each submodules.

Note that the local repo in the directory act as a "parent repo" for those submodules, and is purely local: no need to push that repo. It is just there to benefit from the **[submodule tracking branch feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309)** introduced in git 1.8.2+ (March 2013).

Your git project repos can ignore completely the fact they are submodules for the parent directory repo.

In one command, you trigger a fetch + checkout of the latest commits on `origin/dev` for *all* your git project repos.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using zsh, you could use https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git-auto-fetch:

> Automatically fetches all changes from all remotes while you are working in git-initialized directory.

Just add to `plugins`:

> ```
> plugins=(... git-auto-fetch)
> ```

Comment: This works but seems like creating lags typing in the shell or using emacs once in a while

Answer (score 0):

Might be late for the party but [I wrote a tool for Windows and macOS](https://github.com/awaescher/RepoZ) to auto-fetch multiple repositories (and other features):

[image: RepoZ]

Comment: is there any tool like this for linux?

Comment: RepoZ is not available for Linux, I don't know about others.