# git pull all repositories

Tags: git, ubuntu

I have set up a folder system where I keep all my code within one super folder, within this super folder are around more then 30 different sub folders each containing various projects. Many of these contain git repositories. Now I would like to be able to pull all of them at the same time. Preferably while making it so that if I add a git repository to this folder it will automatically adopt towards the "pulling at the same time", as a bonus is there also a way to make it check recursively so that if I have a folder containing more git repositories these will also pull?

I'm on Ubuntu if that matters.

Comment: Other options: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25707742/6309

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this is to use [git submodules.](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Answer (score 1):

You work with Ubuntu. Write a shell script and put your commands in it.

`cd /yourdir/;git pull origin master;`

Then write every project in one line. Otherwise you can write a for loop and read the folder dynamicly.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/