# What is the proper way to merge two repositories, and pull updates?

Tags: git, merge, repository, zurb-foundation, flat

I would like to get a base to start with for a redesign, using [Almost Flat UI](https://github.com/websymphony/almost-flat-ui). I already have a repository (empty at the moment) for the website I'll be pushing changes to. Since Almost Flat is marked to update to Foundation 5.4 soon, I'd want to pull in those changes when they occur. I don't if there's an easy way to do this automatically, but what would be a simple way of going about this?

I've never "merged" a repository with another, if that's what is required.

But, since Foundation is more regularly maintained, should I merge with that as it regularly updates? I still would like to have updates from Almost Flat whenever it updates, too, I suppose, since I'm not sure how drastic changes are for each version of Foundation's CSS/SCSS. If I were to copy the CSS/SCSS for Almost Flat at this point and not regularly pull updates from it in the future, I'm wondering how much needs to adjust to match the updates.

Answer (score 1):

You can register the [`websymphony/almost-flat-ui`](https://github.com/websymphony/almost-flat-ui) repo as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** of your project.
It will be a subfolder of your repo, without taking much place (it will appear as a [gitlink entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) in your index)

When adding that submodule, you can [configure it to follow a specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309).
That allow you to check if there are any new commits from that branch with:

```
git submodule update --remote
```