# Git submodules and orphaned commits

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repo (A) where each commit is an orphaned commit with a name (branch).  Git repo B consumes A as a submodule, and as such is always holding a reference to a SHA in A.  When I make a fresh clone of B I need to do the typical `git submodule init/update` incantation, but I don't want it to clone all of A.  I just want it to clone the single orphaned commit which is the submodule reference.

However, even when I try `git submodule update --init --recursive --depth 1 path/to/A`, git clones from master instead. Is there a way I can convince it to clone only the SHA that I care about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `B` consumes `A` as a submodule, it should do so by [configuring `A` submodule to follow a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309).

That way, a `git submodule update --init --recursive --remote --depth 1 path/to/A` should checkout from the branch it is supposed to follow.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can make this work. I had no idea that submidules had this capability now.