# Git, can sparse checkout be used as submodules?

Tags: git

I have many files and folders I would like to make composition with. The problem with submodules is that I would have to create one repo for each of my files/folders.

Could sparse checkout be a way to keep everything in one repo and still be able pick what I want for a specific composition and also be able to update changes that are made in the main "core" repo ?

Comment: what do you mean ? can you detail a little bit ? thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

No, as I mentioned in your previous question:

Git sparse checkout is for getting part of [one repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560246/git-using-a-repository-as-a-core-base-where-i-can-pick-some-modules-for-another/38560969?noredirect=1#comment64553257_38560969).
That means `MyCompositeRepo1` and `MyCompositeRepo2` would not be independent repo, but the *same* repo as `MyCoreRepo` with different content.

If you intent to keep only one repo, it is best to keep different *branches* with different content.
Ie 3 branches, each one with only the files you need.