# Checkout branch in git submodule

Tags: git

How do I change branches from within a submodule? When I run `git branch` from within the submodule, I see the following output:

```
> git branch
  * (HEAD detached from 229a7b2)
  master
```

How would I put myself on a new branch? Like `development`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply list your branches:

```
git branch -avv
```

And then checkout the one you want

```
git checkout -b myBranch origin/mybranch
```

Or create a new development branch from the commit you currently are:

```
git checkout -b development
```

A submodule is *always* checked out as a **[detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)** (meansing at a SHA1)

When you change that, and make any new commit (or change the current commit by a branch checkout), don't forget to:

- push that commit to the submodule remote repository (its own origin)
- go to the parent repository, and add, commit and push the new submodule SHA1.
  The parent repository stores said submodule SHA1 as a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, a [special entry in its index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309).

Comment: great, thanks! For my specific purposes I never make commits from the submodule, so I guess I'll just need to do `git checkout -b myBranch origin/myBranch`

Comment: @Apollo you can make new commits from within a submodule: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1979194/6309. And you can configure your submodule to follow a branch that way the parent repo can update a submodule to the latest fetched commit of that branch: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309

Comment: I see, so after I checkout to `myBranch` from within the submodule, I can pull new changes from `myBranch` by doing `git pull origin myBranch` right?

Comment: @Apollo Yes, the submodule is a git repo in its own right, with all the usual workflow of a Git repo (fetch/pull/push). You just need to remember to add, commit and push the gitlink in the parent repo (ie record the new state of your submodule in the parent repo)

Comment: Ok great, thank you. So I performed `git checkout -b myBranch origin/mybranch`, but now I don't see `* (HEAD detached from 229a7b2)` anymore. I only see `myBranch` and `master` when I do `git branch`. And when I did `git checkout master` I see `Switched to branch master. Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 138 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.` Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Apollo no it depends on where you want to create your branch. Again that submodule is a Git repo, so simply need checkout the right branch.

Comment: ok. I've been reading up on your other posts and I think I'm starting to understand how this works. Thank you for being so helpful!