# How To Manage Source Control When Adding Existing Project To A Solution

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have this class library that I want to use in several different solutions. Rather than just referencing the dll, I added this project to the solutions via `Add-->Existing Project` and referenced this project from within the others. The rationele was that I do not have to keep the class library solution open all the time and any change I would make to the source code of this library in a different solution would also reflect to the original. But I have a problem with source control. Since it is added as an existing project, Git does not control it in solutions other than the original. Is there a way to commit the original class library project when I make changes on it from another solution?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but in any case adding build artifacts, libraries, binaries, etc., such as DLL files, is not a good idea.  In general, build artifacts should not be versioned by Git.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually the shared project has its own repository. What I am trying to accomplish is to trigger a commit when it is modified in another solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Rather than just referencing the dll, I added this project to the solutions via Add-->Existing Project and referenced this project from within the others.

You can do that manually through [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), making sure that the repo for that solution is [following its own master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309).

```
git submodule add -b master -- /url/library
```

That way, you can on demand refresh the content of that submodule: if any changes have been done elsewhere, a `git submodule update remote` will update its content.

Note that those have to be done in command-line, since Visual Studio support for submodule is still planned: see [UserVoice "Commit changes to a submodule using VS"](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/13316574-commit-changes-to-a-submodule-using-vs) (planned since Oct. 2016)