# Pull git submodule post receive

Tags: git, git-submodules

I currently update a website by pushing the git repository to a remote. The remote then has a post-receive hook which does

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html/ git checkout -f
```

I recently added a submodule in my repository from a different project. I would like to pull from this submodule post-receive.

.gitmodule

```
 [submodule "plugins"]
    path = plugins
    url = https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins.git
```

(yes it's a pelican website, but that's irrelevant)

I imagine it's a matter of adding a `git pull` in the right place in the post-receive hook, but I'm not sure exactly where or how.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured your submodule to [follow the latest commit of a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309) (or [make an existing submodule track a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)), all you need to add is:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html/ git submodule update --remote
```

That will pull said branch from within the submodule.