# How to prevent detached HEAD when merging?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is there any way to config Git to reject a merge if the action will result in a detached HEAD?

I know how to solve the detached HEAD, but I would rather have git to reject the merge-action to avoid the detached HEAD entirely.

The issue occurs when this happens:

1. I am working on a `develop` branch in the main repo and I also comitted some changes in a submodule repository. The `develop` branch is updated to match the newest commit of the submodule.
2. A colleague wants to merge `develop` into the `master`, but forgets to pull the submodule on `master` first. This results in a detached HEAD.

Comment: Since you're tagging git-submodules I guess you should describe your enviroment a little bit more. And what exaxtly you did.

Comment: Ah sorry, it is after merging with a branch. I have a submodule, which causes the detached HEAD. I will change the question - I don't know why I wrote pull instead of merge.

Comment: @Jan Good point. I have updated the question now.

Comment: Where do you have detached HEAD? In the main repo or in submodule repo?

Comment: In the main repo.

Comment: @ThomasClemensen Honestly, I do not see a way, how merge can result in detached HEAD, unless you was on detached HEAD before merge.

Answer (score 0):

A `submodule` is always in detached head state because Git does not keep any information on which branch it has to be.

Git keep track of the `submodule` commit it is connected to because it is stored along with the commit information. When you merge two different branches that are connected to different `submodule` commits, Git cannot checkout a `branch` on the sub-module that's why you have a detached HEAD.

There is no solution to let your sub-modules attached to a branch.

A possible solution to your issue is:

https://github.com/kollerma/git-submodule-tools

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is a possibility to track a branch in git. As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/14583599) you can add a submodule with tracking information.

> Note:

```
git submodule add -b . [URL to Git repo];
                    ^^^
```

> See git submodule [man](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7425fe100fc90b492549f51aa60ac1e70e7f4c9a/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L258-L264) page:
>
> A special value of . is used to indicate that the name of the branch in the submodule should be the same name as the current branch in the current repository.

In my project we use to track the same branch in the subrepo with the special `.` character. E.g. if your main repo is on `development` branch the submodule will track `development` branch. Same is for a `main-main` pair.

This `<branch>` will be written to your `.gitmodules` file as seen below.

```
[submodule "My_submodule"]
    path = <directory>
    url = <url of the submodule>
    branch = .
```

In your example, I assume you would use the master as the tracking branch.