# Separate FE and BE on Heroku but single repo on Github?

Tags: git, github, web, heroku, git-submodules

#### Setup

I have a web project whose front and backends are hosted on Heroku separately. It is stored in my machine as so:

project root
├── **backend**
│   ├──── stuff
│   └──── .git
├── **frontend**
│   ├──── stuff
│   └──── .git
├── project-wide config files
├── scripts
└── README.md

#### Problem

As you know, deployment to Heroku requires the **backend** and **frontend** folders to have their own git folders... but on Github, I want to unify this whole project into one repo, like it is on my machine.

What are the best practices to this issue? Is git submodules a good solution?

I am also entertaining the idea of docker-composing this whole project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is to define a *third* Git repository, one which will reference the other two (front and back).

That reference would be registered as **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, allowing any one [cloning the parent repository](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspecgt) to get the latest of said sub-repositories:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules --remote-submodules
```

Don't forget, when you [add those submodule, to specify a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309) in order for the parent repository to get the latest of those submodules.

Using [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation):

```
git init myProject
cd myProject
git submodule add -b main [/url/repo/front]
git submodule add -b main [/url/repo/back]
git commit -m "Add front and back repositories"
gh repo create myProject --source=.
git push -u origin main
```