# Github repo syncing issue

Tags: git, github

I have two repo, namely repo A and repo B. Repo A takes in repo B's function output (a variable) to run. Repo B is imported into Repo A as a package for it to run every time Repo A is called.

I have made changes to repo B and has successfully merged it in GitHub. However, when I try to make a test-run on repo A, the changes have not been registered/ refreshed.

Is there a way to force the local repo A to refresh, and take in new repo changes from repo B, so that I can make a test-run?

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean by "running" a repo. Are you talking CI, a script you wrote, or what exactly? Without knowing that, or how you've integrated your two repos in the first place, there's no way for us to figure this one out.

Comment: Please link to the repositories (or a reproduction if that's not possible)

Answer (score 0):

You could, if `repoA` has a `repoB` subfolder declared as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** tracking [a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309).

Then your job would have to do a `git submodule update --remote` in order to force repoB to refresh itself (and then do a `git add`/`git commit`/`git push`, in order for repoA to record the new `repoB` state)
Your job could then proceed working in `repoA`, with a `repoB` up to date.